# adaptIntegrate from R package cubature gets an integral wrong by a huge margin

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I ran some tests of various 2D quadrature tools, and `adaptIntegrate` from `cubature` was consistently one of the most precise, *when it worked*.

Trouble is, in some cases it went completely wrong, but not by some decimals, really off the scale, and I don't understand why.

The functions I am trying to integrate, on rectangular (in fact even square) 2D domains, are logical, of the form:

condition_1 & (condition_2 | condition_3 | ...)

This poses no problem at all with any of the tools I tried (`pracma::integral2`, `pracma::quad2d`, `pracma::simpson2d`...).
`adaptIntegrate` however, while providing the best results in most cases, occasionally fails completely.

Example:

```
require(cubature)

# Intersection of a circle of radius 4 centred in (0,0) with a circle of radius 1 centred in (0,0)

adaptIntegrate(function(x) ( (x[1]^2+x[2]^2 <= 16) & ((x[1]-0)^2+(x[2]-0)^2 <= 1) ), c(-4, -4), c(4, 4), absError = 1.e-2 )

#$integral
#[1] 3.141522
#
#$error
#[1] 0.009982141
#
#$functionEvaluations
#[1] 24089
#
#$returnCode
#[1] 0
```

Correct: the integral should be pi*1^2, about 3.142.
Now move the small circle's centre to (1,0). It it still completely contained in the larger circle, so the intersection has still the same area.

```
# Intersection of a circle of radius 4 centred in (0,0) with a circle of radius 1 centred in (1,0)

adaptIntegrate(function(x) ( (x[1]^2+x[2]^2 <= 16) & ((x[1]-1)^2+(x[2]-0)^2 <= 1) ), c(-4, -4), c(4, 4), absError = 1.e-2 )

#$integral
#[1] 0
#
#$error
#[1] 0
#
#$functionEvaluations
#[1] 51
#
#$returnCode
#[1] 0
```

I cannot figure out why this happens. If I use 1.1 instead of 1 for the x of the small circle, it goes back to a very satisfactory estimate.

**Has anyone got any ideas if I am doing anything wrong, or if this is actually a bug?**

Thanks!

PS
2 notes:

1. Yes, I know these examples are trivial, and I could simply use the area of the small circle. The real problem I will need to solve is much less trivial (e.g. the small circle can partly overlap the perimeter of the big one, and there will be many small circles, not only one, also overlapping between them). If I cannot rely on this working for a simple case, I cannot rely on it working for a more complex one, can I?
2. Yes, I saw some of the posts related to inconsistencies with `adaptIntegrate`, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721075/integration-inconsistency-with-adaptintegrate).
   I see this answer there:

> the Cubature C library gives the same results as I report in the question above, and that this is unlikely to be a bug; rather, the h-adaptive cubature routine (to which the R package is an interface) is in some cases less accurate than Cubature's p-adaptive routine, which doubles the number of sampling points in appropriate regions.

How does this help? It does not seem correct to me to say *'it's not a bug'* when the tool actually gives a wrong answer. And besides, `pcubature` in my case was consistently much less good, and gave the same type of error, so...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why `adaptIntegrate`fails to return a reasonable result. You could write to the maintainer of `cubature` or to the original author of this software.

But you can get reasonable results if you restrict the domain of integration to a rectangle around the smaller/smallest circle !

It is preferable to define the function such that it returns numeric
values. This is also easier to write it down for several circles.

```
fn10 <- function(xy) {
    x <- xy[1]; y <- xy[2]
    (x^2+y^2 <= 16) * ((x-1)^2 + y^2 <= 1)
}

fn40 <- function(xy) {
    x <- xy[1]; y <- xy[2]
    (x^2+y^2 <= 16) * ((x-4)^2 + y^2 <= 1)
}

library(cubature)

adaptIntegrate(fn10, lowerLimit = c(0, -1), upperLimit = c(2, 1))
## $integral
## [1] 3.141828

adaptIntegrate(fn40, lowerLimit = c(3, -1), upperLimit = c(5, 1))
## $integral
## [1] 1.490316
```

I got interested and attempted to find a better value for the area of `f40` with different integration routines.

```
library(pracma)

fun40 <- function(x, y)
    (x^2+y^2 <= 16) * ((x-4)^2 + y^2 <= 1)

quad2d(fun40, 3, 5, -1, 1, n = 512)                ## 200 ms
## [1] 1.489193

integral2(fun40,  3, 5, -1, 1)                     ##   3 ms
## [1] 1.494751

simpson2d(fun40, 3, 5, -1, 1, nx = 512, ny = 512)  ##  16 ms
## [1] 1.487213
```

So what is the true value of this integral?
The two circles intersect at `x0 = 31/8`, thus the 1-dimensional
(vectorized) function to integrate on the interval `[3, 4]` is:

```
x0 <- 31/8.0
fun <- function(x) {
    ifelse(x <= x0, sqrt(1 - (x-4)^2), sqrt(16 - x^2))
}

2 * quadgk(fun, 3, 4)
## [1] 1.487332
```

We doubled the integral because we only integrate above the x-axis.
This should be exact up to an error of about 0.00025. And we see
that the simple Simpson 2D quadrature comes quite close.

NOTE: We can also utilize trigonometric formulae to calculate the area, which is the area of two circle segments, thus

```
# circle at (0.0)               circle at (4,0)
th1 = 2*acos(x0/4);             th2 = 2*acos((4-x0)/1)
A1 = 0.5*(th1 - sin(th1))*16;   A2 = 0.5*(th2 - sin(th2))*1

A1 + A2
## [1] 1.487332
```

This value agrees with the one found previously with the help of a one-dimensional integration.

Comment: Thank you Hans W. I have more than just one or two circles, so I can't restrict the rectangle. The domain to integrate is a rather complicated one, made of many small circles, partly overlapping, of which I want the union (how would you express that as a number?) and this union must then be intersected with the large circle. [This](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110592/can-you-irrigate-your-lawn-with-23-sprinklers/110825?noredirect=1#comment311673_110825) is the original problem. Yes, pure geometry is an option, but not a very easy one to implement in such a case.

Comment: As for writing to the authors, it's not something I do very often, and in this case I cannot see any obvious contact details, at least in CRAN's official webpage of the package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cubature/index.html . Given the answer that was given to other posts pointing out issues with adaptIntegrate, not sure it's worth it. If I am not doing anything wrong with my code, and the issue is indeed a bug with the cubature function, then I'll accept it and use other tools.

Comment: All this can be handled. You provided a simple example and you get a simple answer. That's life. If you want a more complex answer, open a new thread with a real example from your application. BTW: I think if you are using Open Source software, you are in a certain way commited to submit bug reports. That will help make things better for all of us.

Comment: OK thanks Hans W., then I suppose your answer should have stopped at the first sentence. I did make a note (n. 1) that the actual problem was more complex, and I was keeping it simple for brevity and to get to the point. And indeed, my main question was whether there was anything wrong with my code, or rather a bug in the tool I was using. Now we know for sure it is the latter. Committed to submit bug reports, OK, I accept that, and I did do that when I could (for package proxyC for instance). When there are no contact details for me to address anyone, well...(?)

Comment: Maintainer: B. Narasimhan <naras at stat.stanford.edu>. That's what it says in the Description file, and it is obvious. It also links to the Github page and there you will find the e-mail address of the author of the Cubature C library.

Comment: All right, no need to have a go at me. What is obvious to you might not be so obvious to me, and vice versa in fact.